# Python mysql connection timeout AFTER connection has been made with RDS via lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, mysql-connector

I am trying to set up a lambda which connects to two RDS instances. The function code is written in Python, which uses mysql connector to connect to the DB's. This part is working fine. However, when I try to select something from the DB the first call works, after that the lambda times out.

Lambda error: `Task timed out after 5.01 seconds`

RDS logs: `[Note] Aborted connection XXXXX to db: 'X' user: 'X' host: 'XXXXX.compute.amazonaws.com' (Got an error writing communication packets)`

I create a connection like this:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user = os.environ['USER'],
                                          password = os.environ['PASSWORD'],
                                          host = os.environ['IP'],
                                          port = os.environ['PORT'],
                                          database = os.environ['NAME'])
return cnx
```

This connection will be used throughout the code.

Comment: What do the Lambda & RDS logs have to say about the session?

Comment: Lambda logs only state a timeout, RDS logs this `[Note] Aborted connection XXXXX to db: 'X' user: 'X' host: 'XXXXX.compute.amazonaws.com' (Got an error writing communication packets)`

Comment: Please add this text to the question. It seems to me like a one-time networking issue. Are you able to reproduce it?

Comment: this happens every time in the function code of the lambda.

Comment: What makes you think that the Lambda function times-out while doing a DB operation? Is the function interfacing with any other service besides the DB?

Comment: I've changed the function code to only retrieving a specific column of a table in a loop. the first SELECT goes fine, when the code arrives at `cursor.execute(query)` for the second time, the lambda time outs

Comment: See below a probable explanation for what you are experiencing.

Comment: @sems is your lambda running within the same vpc as your RDS?

Comment: @Kulasangar yes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task timeout is probably set to 5 seconds.

The task is timing out because it's taking too long to complete, not because of any communication problem with the DB.

Increase the timeout setting or make the function run faster.

Comment: The function is just a simple SELECT, it shouldn't take too much time. Nevertheless, setting the time-out 5 minutes did not solve it.

Comment: @sems Do you now get a 300 seconds timeout message?

Comment: yes, the lambda gives a 300 seconds timeout, RDS error is the same.

Comment: @sems Have you tried running it without Lambda in order to see how long it takes?

Comment: The problem was that the query took longer than the lambda timeout.